# Not able to modify the numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner in python . I am trying to modify a numpy array but somehow it is not getting modify. Here is my program

```
def test_numpy(x):
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        i-=np.max(i)
        i=(np.exp(i)/np.sum(np.exp(i)))
        print "The value of i is "
        print i
        x[count] = i
        count+=1
        print "the value of x is "
        print x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_numpy(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])).
```

The output it prints is :

The value of i is 
[0.26894142 0.73105858]
the value of x is 
[[0 0]
 [3 4]]
The value of i is 
[0.26894142 0.73105858]
the value of x is 
[[0 0]
 [0 0]]

I am assuming the value of x should be overridden by the value of i . So after looping twice the value of x should become 
([0.26894142 0.73105858],[0.26894142 0.73105858]) But somehow the value is not getting overridden. Can anyone please point out my mistake here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input array is of type `int`, so no floating point numbers can be saved. You have to provide a float array:

```
q=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=float)
test_numpy(q)
print q
```

or you don't change the array, but create a new one, then the resulting type is automatically chosen correctly:

```
def test_numpy(x):
    x = np.exp(x - x.max(axis=1)[:, None])
    return x / x.sum(axis=1)[:, None]

q = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a = test_numpy(q)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
i=(np.exp(i)/np.sum(np.exp(i)))
```

You are creating a new variable, you are not changing the data in place. You forgot to tell Python to modify the data:

```
i[:]=(np.exp(i)/np.sum(np.exp(i)))
```